# Larvel 5.8: How to use static $appends without entire relationship be appended?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Classic situation where `App\Customer` has many `App\User`

**Customer.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

    public function getUserCountAttribute()
    {
        return $this->users->count();
    }
}
```

Serving data as json via API, I'm using

```
Customer::orderBy($order_by, $order_direction)->paginate(10);
```

Obataining, for example (mock data)

```
{
    "id": 34,
    "name": "Angelita Bailey",
    "created_at": "2019-05-07 15:49:47",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-07 15:49:47",
    "deleted_at": null
},
```

If I use static appends ...

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public $appends = [ 'userCount' ];
    ..
}
```

I got *not only* userCount, but also the *full array* of `users` relationship ! I don't want this...

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Carter Osinski",
    "created_at": "2019-05-07 15:49:47",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-07 15:49:47",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "userCount": 1,
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "ipurdy",
            "email": "schultz.joelle@example.com",
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "role": "CUSTOMER",
            "customer_id": 12,
            "created_at": "2019-05-07 15:49:49",
            "updated_at": "2019-05-07 15:49:49",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ]
},
```

### Question

**Why does this happens?**

Comment: can you try `$this->users()->count()` instead of `$this->users->count()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you call $this->users here you close the query before counting the items, so it ends up you call https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-count instead of the eloquent one that we want.

```
public function getUserCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->users->count();
}
```

Basically when you do $this->users it's like doing $this->users()->get() so you get the entire collection on your object.
You can solve this just adding the brackets on the users relationship to keep the query builder open.

```
public function getUserCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->users()->count();
}
```

It should make the job for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is because when you access a relationship as a property it loads the relationship (if it isn't already loaded).

If you want to get the count without loading the relationships then use the relationship method instead:

```
public function getUserCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->users()->count();
}
```

When you access a relationship as a method it will return an instance of `Relation`. This will mean you will have access to the Query Builder so you can call the [count()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#aggregates) method on that which will perform a count query. In the example you've provide you're actually calling [count()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-count) on the collection.